# Queue reduction algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, queue

I have a queue of activities shared between clients, capturing user activity and executed by a robot on the other site. An example of activites might be like:

```
CREATE FOLDER  /docs
CREATE FILE    /docs/journal.txt
DELETE FILE    /docs/blog.txt
MOVE   FOLDER  /docs/images /docs/photos
...
```

Often there are activites that can be reduced to a single one, or none. For instance:

```
CREATE FOLDER /docs
RENAME FOLDER /docs /documents
```

Can be simply changed to:

```
CREATE FOLDER /documents
```

And something like:

```
CREATE FOLDER /docs
RENAME FOLDER /documents
DELETE FOLDER /documents
```

Can be removed entirely from the queue.

This kind of reduction/optimization seems like a very generic problem, and before attacking it I'd like to try some generic solution. It looks like a pathfinding optimization problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any library or framework that would do this for you. On the other hand, you would have to specify the logic behind it yourself, and as I see it, that would be the bulk of the work anyway.

Here's the approach I would take:

1. Do a topological sort of the actions (rename folder "depends on" create folder and so on...)
2. Each command with no dependencies represents a "root" in a dependency tree.
3. Collapse these trees recursively starting from each root.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a library, but if there was one I would be happy. Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "collapse the trees"?

Answer (score 1):

One option (albeit a somewhat heavyweight one) would be to walk over the queue records and simulate the operations that are performed on the file system on a tree representation that you create inside the program.  You could track, for each directory that's referenced, what net operations end up being performed on it.  Once you're done, you could then walk over the modified tree structure and output a series of commands representing the net transformation applied to each directory and subdirectory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Define all of your operations (create, rename, move)
2. Define a Command class that contains your operation + parameters for the operation.
3. Implement something that will tell you if two commands can be combined as well as the what the result of that combination what be.

I have to assume that you can only combine commands that are immediately following each other or else you could potentially introduce unwanted side effects.  So when you go to execute a command off yoru queue, start peeking/popping/building up a command until you encounter a command that cannot be combined into it.

Comment: Thanks for the good intentions, but I think you don't understand the problem. First, the implementation details aren't relevant, I'm just looking for an algorithm. Second, the commands might not necessarily be adjacent, so what you propose either wouldn't work, or would demand an n*n search. There are better obvious solutions if I'm willing to afford that.

Comment: I will be extremely surprised if you find an O(n) or O(1) way to match n elements by the result of an op on them (where op = areTheyCombinable?)  As to the first part of your response, you can take the algorithm out of my implementation details.  I provided the code snapshot as an attempt to help you.  Good luck and hopefully you find this magic solution I'd love to see it too.

Comment: Also please explain how you think you can reorder items in your queue without possible introducing unwanted side effects.  eg:  1=CreateFile(A, "hey you!"), 2=SendEmail(someone@example.com, ContentsOf(A)), 3=DeleteFile(A).      If you really want #1 and #3 to be combined (by definition they can be), you will break #2.

Comment: I'm glad you are willing to help, but your answer wasn't helpful. Sorry. Taking personally criticism directed at your ideas isn't helpful for the site and the community, neither is downvoting the question because of that.

Comment: I do not take it personally, I would like to know the answers to these questions.  I honestly don't think you can reorder your queue, I'd like to know how you plan to deal with side effects.

Comment: I have no intentions of reordering the queue, I just want to remove redundancy. The case you point obviously wouldn't be affected, since there's no redundancy.